# Justify $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = \lim_{\theta\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( \theta \cdot \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n\theta} \right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation, riemann-sum

> I encounter the following equation
> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = \lim_{\theta\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( \theta \cdot \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n\theta} \right).$$

Intuitively, I think the limit on the RHS is related to Riemann sum.
However, I am not able to understand the reason behind it.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I think the intuition of Riemann sums is in the right direction. Perhaps we may consider intervals of length $\Delta x = \theta$ and note that from the definition of Riemann sums $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i^*)\Delta x$ we have $n \rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow \Delta x = \theta \rightarrow 0 $.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answers your question or not. The LHS is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is well-known. Now you work on the RHS like this:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n}&=&\Im\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{n\theta}i}{n}\\
&=&-\Im\ln(1-e^{\theta i})\\
&=&-\Im\ln[(1-\cos(\theta))-i\sin\theta]\\
&=&-\Im\ln\left\{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\left[\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)-i\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right]\right\}\\
&=&-\Im\ln\left\{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\left[\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]\right\}\\
&=&-\left(\frac{\theta}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ \lim_{\theta\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( \theta \cdot \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n\theta} \right)=\frac{\pi}{2}. $$

Comment: It would be better if we can prove the equality directly instead of evaluating both sides.